# Check if $id = column value, else

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if the value $id already exist in the column id.
If it does i want to call a query, else i want to do another query.

Seems quite easy, but not for me.

Here's the important code

```
if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
$data = json_decode($_GET['data'], true);
$id = $data['id'];
$latitude = $data['latitude'];
$longitude = $data['longitude'];
$timestamp = $data['timestamp'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locatie WHERE id='$id'");
if("id='$id'")
{
$query = "Update locatie 
SET     longitude = '$longitude',
   latitude = '$latitude',
   timestamp = '$timestamp'
WHERE id = '$id'";}
else
//Als het nummer bekend is

{
//Als het een nieuw nummer is
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ", mysql_real_escape_string($id) , mysql_real_escape_string($longitude),  mysql_real_escape_string($latitude), mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp));}



$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
echo "OK";

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);
}
```

But now the code wont do anything, i know both of the queries work fine seperatelym but not when i SELECT From locatie....

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is that? `if("id='$id'")`

Comment: `if("id='$id'")` where you are fetching result of id?

Comment: I dont know how to do that...

Comment: SQLi vulnerabilities FTW! http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Secure your first SELECT statement against injection! Always escape!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_num_rows() Get number of rows in result
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

```
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
   //$id already exist in the column id. 

}else {

}
```

Comment: What if between the execution of your SELECT and the INSERT another process inserts the ID you were looking for? This will fail when you least expect it, go for the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE route. If you do not want to UPDATE, simply INSERT and see if you get an error because of duplicate keys, and then do your alternative query. Do not SELECT and act on this info.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple use:

`if( $result && mysql_num_rows($result) )`

as you are doing the check for the `id` already in the query.

As you are not checking if there is a valid result check I added that to the if too.

note: all mysql* functions are deprecated, use mysqli of pdo functions instead.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as you are updating if it exists, or inserting if it does not you could use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Example (should work but is untested)

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ", mysql_real_escape_string($id) , mysql_real_escape_string($longitude),  mysql_real_escape_string($latitude), mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp));
$sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE longitude=VALUES(longitude), latitude=VALUES(latitude),timestamp=VALUES(timestamp)";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locatie WHERE id='$id'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
//do something
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use **REPLACE**, you don't need to perform any *id* checks.

For example:

```
REPLACE INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

Details:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query that way

```
if($result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locatie WHERE id='$id'"))
{
    // Found
}
else
{
    // Not found
}
```

It will return true only if the resource isn't null.